# Clean up HTML code from style attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a `contenteditable` and the option to copy the HTML code of the user’s text. I want to remove the `style=""` attribute that gets added to some elements by the browser. For example:

```
<h2>what</h2><p><span style="color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.77777778em;">what is&nbsp;this</span><span style="color: rgb(54, 54, 54); font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.77777778em;">&nbsp;</span></p><p></p>
```

How can I do it with jQuery?

I’ve tried but it doesn’t work:

```
$('#post_content').keydown(function(e) {
  // if ctrl + e
  if ((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && e.keyCode == 69) {
    var html = $('#post_content').removeAttr('style').html();
    prompt("Ctrl+C to copy HTML code", html);
  }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#post_content *").removeAttr("style");
prompt("Ctrl+C to copy HTML code", $("#post_content").html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WHRST/

You have to select all of the descendents of your contenteditable element. So you use the (*) in the select, once you have all of the descendents you can call the .removeAttr("style") and it will be removed from every element in the collection.

Comment: followup question: can I do something like this (storing the HTML elements in a var and calling to remove attribute from that var)? (it’s not working currently):

`var select = getHTMLOfSelection();
select = select.removeAttr('style');`

Comment: @Alex - jQuery results are collections (lists) of jQuery objects. Those objects represent the jQuery enhanced HTML DOM elements. You can't just take the HTML string value and try to call jQuery functions on it.

Answer (score 3):

[`removeAttr()` should work fine for this purpose](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/y3PyZ/).

I suspect the problem is your selector -- `#post_content` is not in the sample HTML you provided.